# sql server insert statement into table 2 from table 1 with where specifications

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. ContractPlan and JobPlan. I want to populate JobName in the JobPlan table with the JobName from ContractPlan table that has a probability of 100 and is not already in the JobPlan table.

Also how could you put that into a trigger so when the probability gets updated to 100, then the insert happens. Or even a stored procedure which I could execute via asp.net button.

My Current non-working statement:

```
insert into JobPlan (JobName)
select cp.JobName
from ContractPlan cp
Where cp.Prob = 100 and JobPlan.JobName != cp.JobName
```

Thanks

Comment: what does it mean - non working.... does the select without the insert into provide any results?

Comment: `JobPlan.Jobname` can't be accessed as it's not present in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into JobPlan (JobName)
select cp.JobName
from ContractPlan cp
Where cp.Prob = 100 and cp.JobName not in (select JobName from JobPlan)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into JobPlan (JobName)
    select cp.JobName
      from ContractPlan cp
     Where cp.Prob = 100 
       and not exists(
         select * 
           from JobPlan jp
          Where jp.JobName = cp.JobName)
```